# The level read from a microcontroller Pin

Tags: microcontroller

I want to verify the level read by uC1 in the following config:

uC1|---------|uC2

The pin is shared directly between two uCs 1 and 2 without any external circuit. Each pin has a particular configuration:

uc1: Input with no pull

uC2: Output with Pull-up.

Theoretically, we will read the following values:

From uC1:

- HIGH when uC2 doesn't set the level or when it set the level to HIGH
- LOW only if uC2 set the level to LOW.

Is this analysis correct?

Comment: Yes if "doesn't set the level" means high impedance (set to neither HI nor LO, and includes setting UC2 as an input or cutting the trace for UC2 as well.)

Comment: For practical reasons, please add a series resistor between the pins to limit current when someone inevitably configures the pins improperly, and they short each other out.  However, your analysis may be incomplete because depending on the uC, an output pin may be either high or low until you dictate what it is suppose to be in software (even with a pull-up enabled).  Read your datasheet.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen,  Interesting! How they  can short each other out? Could you please provide an example of scenario that leads to that phenomena?

Comment: You're probably already aware of this, but you'll need a common ground for the circuit to work.  And you may well run into problems if one chip is powered and the other is not (particularly if it's the sending one that is powered).

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Are both MCUs running off the same power supply or can one be powered while the other isn't? Are they driven by the same reset signal or have they internal reset circuits that'll start each MCU at different times? Your sw must cope when things aren't running normally - that sometimes gets forgotten. As @ChrisKnudsen rightly says, use a linking series resistor to limit the current if, in development etc, both pins are inadvertently driven as push-pull outputs of opposing levels. Calculate its value from both the MCU internal pull-up value and the push-pull's Ioutmax.

Comment: @TonyM, Thank you! Both MCUs are supplied by a PMIC and the reset signals also comes from one pin from PMIC. I can confirm that both MCUs are powered in the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Please can you edit it into your question, rather than post it in comments. Otherwise new readers have to piece together the full question. Also, please add your MCU part number and a schematic. The schematic editor here is a breeze to use or you can post your existing schematic (avoid a photo of a hand-drawn sketch though).